# Reset bios password

Tags: security, bios

I have a Fujitsu lifebook s762 but the bios is lock by a password and i have the difficulty to reset it. I had use CMOSPWD, the password don't reset.  I had remove cmos pile and the pc ask me always a password even when the cmos pile is in my hand.

Help me please.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with "cmos pile"? Does it mean the same as "cmos battery"?

Comment: @ZN13 `pile` is `battery` in French and can also sometimes refer to it so probably, since `CMOS pile` doesn't really mean anything else.

Comment: thanks for the setsumei, never seen pile being used as battery. If the asker has already tried having the battery (and all other power sources) out for over 5 minutes and it didn't work then there's probably not a lot you can do. Some motherboards have clear jumper you could try. If it doesn't have one or trying to set it fails then you're out of luck. Contact the manufacturer.